# Execute a cat command within a sed command in Linux

Tags: linux, sed, cat

I have a `file.txt` that has some content. I want to search for a string in `file1.txt`, if that string is matched I want to replace that string with the content of the `file.txt`. How can I achieve this?

I have tried using `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/%d/cat file.txt/g' file1.txt
```

This is searching for the matching string in the `file1.txt` and replacing that with the string `cat file.txt`, but I want contents of `file.txt` instead.

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: @amar , could you specify or give a example in your question so that readers understand it better

Comment: Does the `file.txt` contain one line or many lines?  Should the line breaks in the file be preserved or can it be treated as a single line with newlines replaced by blanks?

Answer (score 6):

How about saving the content of the file in the variable before inserting it into sed string?

```
$content=`cat file.txt`; sed "s/%d/${content}/g file1.txt"
```

Comment: You can do: sed "s/%d/$(cat file.txt)/g" file1.txt too.

Comment: @uzsolt Yes, but I prefer variables, because they're more readable.

Comment: @amar If you've found another solution, please, add an answer, so other people can see this has been answered and don't waste their time, if they want to answer, or look in if they have the same question.

Comment: You need `content=$(cat file.txt); sed ...`, and this won't work if there happen to be any `/`, `&`, or probably a couple other sequences in the file.

Comment: sed -e 's/%d/'$a'/g' amar.htm           
this solved my issue amar.htm having the string "%d" which is indeed to be searched and "a" is having the string to replace.

Answer (score 3):

Given `original.txt` with content:

```
this is some text that needs replacement
```

and `replacement.txt` with content:

```
no changes
```

I'm not sure what your replacement criteria is, but lets say I want to replace all occurrences of the word `replacement` in the *original* file, you may replace the content of the original text with the content of the other file using:

```
> sed -e 's/replacement/'"`cat replacement.txt`"'/g' original.txt
this is some text that needs no changes
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read a file with `sed` using the `r` command.  However, that is a line-based operation, which may not be what you're after.

```
sed '/%d/r file1.txt'
```

The read occurs at the end of the 'per-line' cycle.

Answer (score 1):

the e flag for s command does the trick: you can execute shell command in the second part of a s(ubstitue) command:

```
sed 's/%d/cat file1.txt/e'
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command

> If a substitution was made, the command that is found in pattern space is executed and pattern space is replaced with its output.